# Looking for a self-hosted software to track where I'm spending my time while I'm using my devices

Tags: open-source, productivity

I'm looking for a self hosted way of tracking where I'm spending most of my time while I'm using my laptop and my smartphone so I could determine how productive I am while using them and what can I do to be a bit more productive.

I actually found a way of doing this. I was using this one service called [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/). It worked great, *but*, I'm having troubles trusting someone with all that data. Basically, once I was using them, their server tracked how much was I using my applications and how much time did I spend on certain websites. While this is exactly what I am looking for, I'm not comfortable with sharing this info with any company.

So, I'm looking for a self hosted way of accomplishing this.

This solution needs to be compatible with Linux and Android.